# How to convert list to dataframe in R when retrieving data from MySQL

Tags: r, dplyr

it may seems simple, however somehow I am unable to convert list into dataframe in R:

```
>   customer_name <- "xyz"
>   q_times <- paste0("SELECT * FROM mytable.params WHERE name = '",customer_name,"'")
>   
>   suppressWarnings({
+     rs = dbSendQuery(connect_replica(), q_times)
+   })
>   
>   df_params<- as.data.frame(fetch(rs, n=-1))
> typeof(df_params)
[1] "list"
> 
>   df_params<- data.frame(fetch(rs, n=-1))
> typeof(df_params)
[1] "list"
> 
>   df_params <- df_params  %>% as_tibble()
> typeof(df_params)
[1] "list"
> 
>   df_params <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(df_params), nrow=length(df_params), byrow=TRUE))
> typeof(df_params)
[1] "list"
```

Any idea what might be wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: Use `class` instead of `typeof`.

Comment: Side notes: (1) Is there a reason you are choosing to use `dbSendQuery` and multiple calls to `fetch` instead of a single call to `dbGetQuery` for all data? (2) "Never" add data or parameters to a query using `paste`, `paste0`, or `sprintf`, even inadvertent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) can be a pain (that's not the only reason). A better option is to use [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Comment: (3) `fetch` is already returning a `data.frame`, there is no need for `as.data.frame(.)`.  Other than the use `typeof` instead of `class`, did you actually try to look at `df_params` itself to see what it looks like? If it's a lot of data, you might prefer `str(df_params)` to see its basic `str`ucture, but my guess is that everything is actually just fine.